# Is there a good way to open a file from within Neovim in a VSCode project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

Say I have a project in a directory called `project-foo`. This project has multiple files and subdirectories.

In vim/neovim, my `pwd` is `project-foo` and my open buffer is `project-foo/src/test/bar.js`.

**How can I open this file in VSCode in the project context (not individual file by itself)?**

Another way to ask: is there a way to get VSCode to open with the project context and specifically focus a particular file?

Expanding on this, let's say I want to open the specific file `project-foo/src/test/bar.js`. I could type `code project-foo/src/test/bar.js'. But that opens VSCode with only awareness of that specific file unless VSCode already has this project open.

I essentially want the equivalent of:

```
> cd project-foo
> code .

(in VSCode) ⌘+p src/test/bar.js <enter>
```

but in command line form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given it'll open the file in the context of the project if VSCode is already open to the project, you can accomplish this (and handle when VSCode isn't launched) with the following semi-hack:

```
> cd project-off
> code . && code -g ./src/test/bar.js
```

In vim/neovim, you could add a keymap that executes the following

`:!code . && code -g %`

Explanation:

`!` will run the proceeding text as a shell command

`code .` will open the current project

`&& code %` will then execute vscode again but with with the current buffer path (magic `%`)

---

An improvement on this if you want to navigate to a particular line and column

```
    vim.keymap.set.("n", "<leader>ox",
      function()
        local r, c = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
        vim.cmd('!code . && code -g ' .. vim.fn.expand('%') .. ':' .. r .. ':' .. c)
      end,
      { desc = '[O]pen E[x]ternal editor' }
    )
```

- `vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)` gets you the cursor position
- `!code . && code -g ' .. vim.fn.expand('%') .. ':' .. r .. ':' .. c` is ultimately `code . && code -g [file]:[row]:[column]`

Comment: This will break, if there is no buffer (yet) and the project was never opened in VSCode, but other than that, it works. I did `local g = vim.fn.expand('%') .. ':' .. r .. ':' .. c vim.cmd('!codium . && codium -g ' .. g .. ' || code . && code -g ' .. g)` to prioritize Codium. You might also want to save first with `vim.cmd('wall')` and you can also auto-quit vim with a followed `vim.cmd('q!')` if you like. Nice.